# Is there a way to use bit.ly account when shortening links in Twitter app?

Tags: twitter

I have a bit.ly account, and I want to be able to track my shortened links. However, using the Twitter, it allows me to choose what shortening I use, but I can't seem to find an option to have any shortened links linked to my bit.ly account.

I know that my twitpic account is used to upload pictures (and I've set twitpic as the default), but I want to know if there is a way to do this with bit.ly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a way in the Twitter app, but if you really want that functionality, Seesmic has it.

Comment: Oooh, sessmic! I thought that was only for rooted phones! Cheers for that!

Comment: A word of advice: it's terribly slow. At least on my Galaxy S.

Answer (score 1):

And [HootSuite](http://hootsuite.com/android) has their ow.ly shortener

See other options @ [comparison of twitter apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/358/comparision-of-twitter-apps/362#362)